# How to quick-sort a 1D array based on 3rd column (index divided by 3) in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, qsort

I have a 1D array which is `a[9]={33888,32567,3,32678,31967,2,32333,32456,0}`. It cannot be converted to 2d array because 2d array is not allowed. Actually there are three columns in this 1d array like this:

```
A         B          C
33888     32567      3
32678     31967      2
32333     32456      0
```

So the sorting output based on column C in 1d array will be:

```
32333
32456
0
32678
31967
2
33888
32567
3
```

This array need to be sort based on column C that is all indexes divided by 3 in 1d array. But this array can not be represented as 2d array. I need to quick-sort this using 1D array. I have implemented bubble-sort but it is slow. Can anyone help by implementing quick-sort of this problem in C++? If anyone can do this by built in sort function using 1d array then it will be also work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the code you have already tried?

Comment: Does creating a struct that has the columns as fields, and sorting a 1D array of the structs satisfy the requirements?

Comment: [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is your friend.

Comment: @cigien Thanks for comment. !d array can not be converted to another 2d or struct array. if you can sort this with 1d array then it will be work for me. I have added by bubble sort code in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the following?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const int *p1 = ( const int * )a;
    const int *p2 = ( const int * )b;

    return ( p2[2] < p1[2] ) - ( p1[2] < p2[2] );
}

int main() 
{
    int a[]  = { 33888, 32567, 3, 32678, 31967, 2, 32333, 32456, 0 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    const size_t M = 3;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << std::setw( 5 ) << a[i] << ' ';
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % M == 0 ) std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::qsort( a, N / M, sizeof( int[M] ), cmp );


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << std::setw( 5 ) << a[i] << ' ';
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % M == 0 ) std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
33888 32567     3 
32678 31967     2 
32333 32456     0 

32333 32456     0 
32678 31967     2 
33888 32567     3
```

That is the number of actual element should be multiple by 3. In general if the number of actual elements is N then a call of `qsort` will look like

```
std::qsort( a, N / 3, sizeof( int[3] ), cmp );
```

provided that there are 3 "columns" in the array.

As for your comment

> Thanks. Can you test this array
>   a[]={32678,32567,3,32678,32567,2,32678,32456,0,32567,32678,0,32067,32078,1}.
>   Your code crushes when i increases the array size. If it works with
>   any size then it will be accepted answer.

then here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const int *p1 = ( const int * )a;
    const int *p2 = ( const int * )b;

    return ( p2[2] < p1[2] ) - ( p1[2] < p2[2] );
}

int main() 
{
    int a[]  = 
    {
        32678, 32567, 3, 
        32678, 32567, 2, 
        32678, 32456, 0, 
        32567, 32678, 0, 
        32067, 32078, 1 
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    const size_t M = 3;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << std::setw( 5 ) << a[i] << ' ';
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % M == 0 ) std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::qsort( a, N / M, sizeof( int[M] ), cmp );


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << std::setw( 5 ) << a[i] << ' ';
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % M == 0 ) std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The [program](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf52201e28f4290e) output is

```
32678 32567     3 
32678 32567     2 
32678 32456     0 
32567 32678     0 
32067 32078     1 

32678 32456     0 
32567 32678     0 
32067 32078     1 
32678 32567     2 
32678 32567     3
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. the output is correct. but what about when the array is a[]={32678,32567,3,32678,32567,2,32678,32456,0,32567,32678,0,32067,32078,1}. I mean, i can not understand about M.

Comment: *"How to quick sort a 1D array"*: By using quick sort ^_^. (ok no guaranty that qsort is really quick sort as its name might suggest).

Comment: @ucoder If you want that the number of columns would be equal to 3 then you have to write std::qsort( a, N / 3, sizeof( int[3] ), cmp ); That is the array has 5 elements of the type int[3].

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks. Can you test this array a[]={32678,32567,3,32678,32567,2,32678,32456,0,32567,32678,0,32067,32078,1}. Your code crushes when i increases the array size. If it works with any size then it will be accepted answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Your M in both versions has different meaning. sad example with `N = 3*3` with column/row easily interchangeable.

Comment: thanks @VladfromMoscow it worked. Can your code work with more than 300000 elements?

Comment: @ucoder I think that it is time for you to select the best answer  and close the question. You can make experiments with arrays yourself. The code can work but you have to declare the array static or allocate it  dynamically because it is too big.